# Trouble installing GMP 5.0.2

Tags: system-installation

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu (11.10, Oneiric Ocelot), so if there is some type of installer that I can double-click, that would be great. Otherwise, can you help me understand what's happening here.

After downloading `gmp-5.0.2.tar.bz2` and extracting it to my Documents folder, I followed [these instructions](http://gmplib.org/manual/Installing-GMP.html), but I'm hitting an error:
`louis@x-pc:~/Documents/gmp-5.0.2$ ./configure`
`[checking various things...]`
`checking for suitable m4... configure: error: No usable m4 in $PATH or /usr/5bin (see config.log for reasons).`
`louis@x-pc:~/Documents/gmp-5.0.2$ make`
`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

`config.log` is actually 180KB, and I really wouldn't know what to look for.

Can you tell me what I should do?

Comment: Is the m4 package installed? (run "sudo apt-get install m4" in terminal), then try ./configure again. Or if you don't feel confortable using the terminal, use the Ubuntu packgae manager to install m4.

Comment: Glad it helped! :)

Comment: @NiclasNilsson you should post that as an answer and Louis should accept it, now that it is confirmed working. This will help both your reputations here.

Comment: I know but it seemed silly to post an answer when I already solved it in the comment (was'nt sure that was the problem). But ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is my answer, so you can accept it and we both gain some points.

You have to install the m4 package.

Use the Ubuntu Package Manager or in terminal print `sudo apt-get install m4`

Answer (score 1):

Installing from the Ubuntu software centre is a breeze! I highly recommend if you are new to Ubuntu that you start there. You can also install "Synaptic package manager" and install applications that way.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul install software from Ubuntu Software Center. It's easier and more straigth forward. There is also an online app site [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com)

Comment: He wants GMP, not GIMP. Software Center is still the easiest, best way for everything else though.

Comment: K, sorry, haven't been paying 100% attention :)

Comment: I read it as GIMP the first time, too. When I clicked the link in the question I realized it was not a mistake. Something looked way off with the version number, too. (GIMP current stable version = 2.6)